Determining Whether This Function is Continuous
Is the function $y = x$ if x is rational, and $y = -x$ if x is not rational, continuous at $x = 0$?
Thank you in advance. I believe it is so by definition, but it is such a strange case.
For any $\epsilon > 0$, we can find $\delta > 0$ such that for any $c$, we have $|c-0| < \delta$ implies $|f(c)-f(0)| < \epsilon$.
This is the case here, I think? Take $\delta = \epsilon$.
What other functions are seemingly not continuous but actually are?

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

What definition do you know of continuity? Have you tried showing continuity?

Being continuous at some point is not so remarkable. You ask for 'other' functions that are continuous but the function you mentioned is not continuous itself. It is only continuous at point $0$.

@drhab I see! Thank you for the insight.

To solve this easily, we can look at an especially useful definition of continuity.

A function $f:E\subset \mathbf{R} \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ is continuous at a point $x\in E$ if for every sequence $\{x_k\}\subset E\setminus\{x\}$ s.t $\lim_{k\to +\infty} x_k = x$, then $\lim_{k\to +\infty} f(x_k) = f(x)$.

To show how powerful this is, let's take take the Dirchlet function, also sometimes denoted $\mathbf{1}_\mathbf{Q}$ in reference to indicating functions:
$$\mathbf{1}_\mathbf{Q}=\begin{cases} 
      1 \hspace{0.5cm} x\in\mathbf{Q} \\
      0 \hspace{0.5cm} x\in\mathbf{R}\setminus\mathbf{Q} 
   \end{cases}$$
We apply the previous definition: Take $a_n\subset\mathbf{Q}$ s.t $\lim_n a_n = x\in\mathbf{R}$, and $b_n\subset\mathbf{R}\setminus\mathbf{Q}$ such that $\lim_n b_n =x\in\mathbf{R}$. If we apply these two sequences to our previous definition of continuity, we clearly see in one case $\lim_{k\to +\infty} f(a_k) = 1$ and in another one: $\lim_{k\to +\infty} f(b_k) = 0$, violating unicity of the limit. We can somewhat think of it as each sequence following a different train track, but never being able to connect (that would be a bad railway system).
In your case, do the two different train tracks connect, if yes at what point, does this answer your question?
Note: we are able to choose two sequences that converge to the same point due to the density of $\mathbf{Q}$ in $\mathbf{R}$.
